# It was often searched for. What is it?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry, history

Maybe it's wooden.

Maybe it's golden.

It could be made out of greenish glass.

Most likely it has not that much mass.

-

Some think it is already found,

Most think it could still be somewhere around.

Hidden at some scary place,

In some ancient buildings base.

-

It is a mystical ancient object.

It's believed to have a great effect.

It's part of stories often told.

It's more than one millennium old.

-

It occurs in middle age lore.

It was often searched for.

-

**What is it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this

> The Holy Grail?

Maybe it's wooden.

> Speculated because Jesus was a carpenter so his cup may have been made of wood.

Maybe it's golden.

> Because of the belief of heavenly wealth.

It could be made out of greenish glass.

> The Santo Calion was a greenish glass chalice believed to be the Grail in the Medieval era.

Most likely it has not that much mass.

> It's a cup, so it's small.

Some think it is already found,

> Some believe it's in a reliquary in a church around the world somewhere.

Most think it could still be somewhere around.

> Most believe it is still missing.

Hidden at some scary place,

> Just like in Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade.

In some ancient buildings base.

> Where it was hidden in an ancient building.

It is a mystical ancient object.

> It is the Cup of Christ.

It's believed to have a great effect.

> The power of everlasting life.

It's part of stories often told.

> In the Bible, in Arthurian legend, in Monty Python, etc.

It's more than one millennium old.

> It's 2 millennia old.

It occurs in middle age lore.

> As part of Arthurian legend.

It was often searched for.

> And was searched for extensively by treasure hunters.

Comment: Beat me by seconds :)

Comment: Close one! Great minds think alike :)

Comment: exactly what i thought.